# how to display an image from the Internet in SimpleAdapter

Tags: android

I have SimpleAdapter in which I want to display an image from the Internet.

```
final String[] from = { ATTRIBUTE_NAME_TEXT, ATTRIBUTE_NAME_IMAGE,ATTRIBUTE_NAME_DESCRIPTION };
final int[] to = { R.id.tvText, R.id.ivImg,R.id.textDescr };

 sAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), data, R.layout.itemvideo, from, to);
                sAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                setListAdapter(sAdapter);
```

I fill the data in a separate thread

```
 for (Element titles : title) {
                m = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                m.put(VideoList.ATTRIBUTE_NAME_TEXT, titles.select("a[href]").text());
                m.put(VideoList.ATTRIBUTE_NAME_IMAGE, Uri.parse(titles.select("img").attr("abs:src")));
                m.put(VideoList.ATTRIBUTE_NAME_DESCRIPTION,titles.select("div[style]").first().text());
                m.put("link",titles.select("a[href]").attr("abs:href"));
                data.add(m);
            }
```

Displayed normal data adapter, but the picture is not displayed. if doing so

```
 m.put(VideoList.ATTRIBUTE_NAME_IMAGE, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

then the standard output adapter icon android, but I need to display an image from the Internet

Comment: Are you getting an error when you do it your original way? Have you tried converting your Uri to a BitmapDrawable?

Comment: use a custom adapter and lazy load the images using picasso or UIL

Comment: no errors, just not displayed. convert to BitmapDrawable not tried, I do not know how to do it. may prompt the code?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use an Universal Image loader for this purpose, what you can do is make a custom list , before show a progress icon or dialog and later replace that with an image loaaded from the internet please visit

**https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader**

Answer (score 0):

It is much better to use a custom adapter as @Raghunandan suggested. You have much more control and it's not that hard.

**First**, create a class that extends ArrayAdapter and pass the type of object you want to handle:

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyObjectModel> {
```

Your adapter must contain a Collection (`List`s are fine) of your `MyModelObject` objects. You can pass this list in the constructor of the adapter and keep a reference in a variable. Each object should have a property with the URL of an image.

**Second**, create a simple layout for each item in your list. Your layout must contain an ImageView somewhere:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" ... >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/myImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ... />
```

**Third**, back to your adapter, you must implement the getView() method. This method returns a view, based on your custom layout, that contains the info from your `MyObjectModel` object at the given position in the list.

- Inflate your layout : `view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_item, null);`
- Get your ImageView component : `imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.myImage);`
- Get the object from the list : `item = list.get(position);`
- Download the image in an asynctask or use a 3rd party tool such as Universal Image Loader, Picasso etc. Personally I use [UrlImageViewHelper](https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper) : `UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(imageView, item.imageURL, ...);`

IMO it's the only way to have a nice and custom list because default Android options don't allow much customization.

Have a look at http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/ for some tips to improve your custom adapter.